# DPAPI + Entropy

Tags: .net, entropy, dpapi

We have a WPF app that allows our users to download encrypted content and we want to provide the ability to decrypt this content off-line. The idea is to download the keys and store them using the DPAPI but I'm having trouble with the entropy parameter.

Is there any way to generate an entropy to consistently use for the DPAPI functions with out hardcoding/storing them?

Thanks
Tony

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585746/securely-storing-optional-entropy-while-using-dpapi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Securely Storing Optional Entropy While Using DPAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585746/securely-storing-optional-entropy-while-using-dpapi)

Anything you store locally can be compromised.  But there are steps you can take to make it more difficult.  There is a document on [Handling Passwords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717799%28VS.85%29.aspx) that you may consider looking over.  You consider your Entropy Key a password specific to your application.

I am going to refer to your Entropy as your *Key*, since it is functionally an additional key.

What you don't want to do is store your key locally in an unencrypted format.  Instead you want to either encrypt your key, or derive it from another, in-obvious source.  Of course if your encrypt the key, then you need to store the key used to encrypt it - but often times this single layer of indirection is enough to discourage most challengers.

That would be the advantage of deriving your key.  You could derive it as a hash of some other piece of constant data (needs to be something that doesn't change with revisions of your application).  One trick when deriving a hash though is to combine the hash with some other constant value (like a GUID or large random number) so that someone else cannot just combine a known hash algorithm and get your key.  This is a much better alternative to creating your own hash algorithm (which you should never do, unless you have a PHD in Mathematics).

At some point your are going to need some sort of key hard coded in your application.  This key is either combined with some other data in a hash to create your Entropy Key, or used to decrypt the entropy key.  You actually can have the key change with a new revision of your application, as long as you keep the old key for decrypting the existing key.  Then you can re-encrypt it with the new key or method.

If you want the best security then you can store the Entropy key off the computer.  This would require an internet connection and an SSL certificate, but then they key is never persisted anywhere locally to be discovered.  To do this you can setup a more robust challenge response system so the request authentication is different each time, and the key is delivered over SSL encryption so it cannot be intercepted.  Once the key is used, then it is discarded.  Of course this kind of defeats the purpose of many scenarios where you are using DPAPI for local secure storage.

Whatever you do, keep in mind it will be compromised - that always happens when someone has full access to the local machine and the data stored on it.  The solution to that is to keep releasing updates that change the method enough that the old crack no longer works.  This will make distribution of a crack less valuable as it will be difficult to find one for the right version.

Comment: Reeeeally old but stumbled across this and would like to point that "Entropy" in DPAPI context is referred as "secondary key". I think this is good to remember that DPAPI provides quite decent protection even without entropy if the useraccount is handled well and has eg. strong password. Entropy add another layer for the encryption key and thus you actually cannot weaken the protection by using it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your usage provides a handy entropy value.  For example, if you wanted to encrypt the password of a web site (as browsers do), your entropy value could be the web site's url.